# Spring boot app deploy to appengine from azure dev ops

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, build

I can make the Azure ops pipeline but my question is I have checkedin my code into repository where we should not checkin the application property file.

That means on the deployment time i should have to download the application property file from some secure place and build my spring boot app before i deploy into app engine right.

So, what i did so far is, I downloaded my application property file into azure agent at run time. I passed the property file into maven build command but it did not work out. [Note: I already searched a lot read a lot of answers and applied as well but nothing worked]

Command line I used:

> mvn -f myapp-springboot-api/pom.xml
>   -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.config.location=file:/home/username/application.properties"
>   clean package appengine:deploy

I also tried with

> mvn -f myapp-springboot-api/pom.xml
>   --spring.config.location=file:/home/username/application.properties 
>   clean package appengine:deploy

This also did not workout.

Also, I tried passing the whole property file location via pom.xml

pom.xml changes:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    <property.file.location>${property.file.location}</property.file.location>
</properties>
<build>
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <files>
                        <file>${property.file.location}</file>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
           </plugins>
</build>
```

Than I tried to build with:

> mvn -f myapp-springboot-api/pom.xml
>   -Dproperty.file.location="/home/username/application.properties" clean package appengine:deploy

Than also I was not able to load the define external property file.

Thanks in advance, please help your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands you are using won't actually pass the external properties files to the application engine (As it exists on a different server) and would only be scoped to the running maven process that is packaging + deploying.

So if you have copied your property file onto the external agent before building I would just replace the default one you have checked into source control.

So your build steps would be for example:

1. Download property file
2. Overlay:

```
mv /home/username/application.properties myapp-springboot-api/src/main/resources/application.properties
```

3. Build + Deploy

```
mvn -f myapp-springboot-api/pom.xml clean package appengine:deploy
```

So now your compiled and deployed jar file would include your new properties file, an alternative that recently came out would be to use something like [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/).

If you want to not have to do another command you could also use the [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) to perform the copy for you.

Comment: I worked out, but I was hoping that through mvn we could able to load the property from outside of classpath that is why i was trying to load it. Anyways thanks finally it work out.